# reveal.js framework + javascript arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, reveal.js

I'm using [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) framework which turns a website into a full page horizontal website.

I'm trying to write some javascript to respond to the click of .navigate-left and .navigate-right arrows.

I've found that the reveal.js class names .navigate-right.enabled works for the right and .navigate-left works for the left.
However, it only responds to the click of the arrows on desktop, it does not work for click or swipe on mobile, and key press, trackpad swipe on desktop (which is supported by the reveal.js framework).

Here's a stripped down example (mouse scroll or mobile swipe to see it not work):
http://chrisriesner.com/DT_web-experiments/DT-reveal-arrows-11-12-13/reveal-arrows-clean.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            // RIGHT ARROW 
            $(".navigate-right.enabled").click(function(){
                $('#side-column-textbox').animate({top: "-=300px"}, 1020);
                })  

            // LEFT ARROW 
            $(".navigate-left").click(function(){
                $('#side-column-textbox').animate({top: "+=300px"}, 1020);
                })      
    })
</script>
```

I've tried a lot of different solutions with no luck, so any help would be great!!

-thanks

Answer (score 1):

I made some progress when I learned about the addEventListener function
I did have to setup a different event name even though the function was the same which makes it kind of messy.
See demo here: 
http://chrisriesner.com/DT_web-experiments/DT-reveal-arrows-11-18-13/reveal-arrows-addevents.html#/

```
        <section >
            <h2>PAGE 0</h2>
        </section >


        <section data-state="data-event-textbox">
            <h2>PAGE 1</h2>
        </section>


        <section data-state="data-event-textbox1">
            <h2>PAGE 2</h2 >
        </section>


        <section data-state="data-event-textbox2">
            <h2>PAGE 3</h2>
        </section>


<script>

    document.addEventListener('data-event-textbox', function(){
        $('#side-column-textbox').animate({top: "-=84%"}, 1020);

    });

    document.addEventListener('data-event-textbox1', function(){
        $('#side-column-textbox').animate({top: "-=84%"}, 1020);

    });

    document.addEventListener('data-event-textbox2', function(){
        $('#side-column-textbox').animate({top: "-=84%"}, 1020);

    })
</script>
```

This got mouse scroll and mobile swipes working with my .animate! However the problem I have now is that when swipe left or click left the function should .animate +=84% instead of the -=84%

Any thoughts on how to trigger the slide when swiping/clicking left so i can animate the opposite way?